# Spacy - making smaller size of library

Tags: pip, python-3.6, spacy

Is it possible to make smaller size of this lib?
Currently in python.36/site-packages/spacy lang is 380MiB folder, where I see a lot of unused languages by me. I use only en, and is it possible to install with pip somehow spacy and load to this folder only needed language?

Comment: How did you install spacy?

Comment: in requirements I have spacy==2.1.0, and then I run python -m spacy download en

Answer (score 0):

This is improved in v2.2+, where the language-specific data has been moved out of the main library into a separate package. The size depends a bit on your OS, but should be closer to ~50 MB.

Answer (score 0):

There's some nice work being done to get the size of Spacy down for serverless deployments like AWS Lambda:
https://github.com/ryfeus/lambda-packs

In addition to trimming down the repository, they also move the language models to S3 to limit the size requirements of the package.

Also see here for a python script to prune the languages:
https://gist.github.com/jshhrrsn/5377b9dd282ef51f5564f1347a7d5aef